# Is there a rich text editor control that does both spell AND grammar checking?

Tags: wpf, winforms, .net-3.5, controls, spell-checking

I'm looking for a winforms or wpf control that can do both spelling and grammar checking in english and also do red & green squiggly underlines, similar to MS Word.

So far, all I've been able to find are spell-checker controls.  I'd be open to good spell checking and grammar checking libraries as well - if you can recommend an integration point with the editor that allows for the underlining.

Comment: Personally, I find MS Word's grammar checking to be _really_ useless.

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately, it's the grammar checker that's on the requirement list (and its hard to find at that)...

Comment: Hi Zachary. What did you end up doing? Six years later and it seems that things aren't much better.

Comment: @AndreLuus I forgot about this question! I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

For historical context, we eventually went with CKEditor and AfterTheDeadline.  We use CKEditor on our current project, but I haven't seen any progress from ATD in recent years.

http://ckeditor.com/
https://github.com/ckeditor

http://www.afterthedeadline.com/
https://github.com/Automattic/atd-ckeditor